# euclidian algorithm proof

Tags: proof-writing, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

I am having difficulty with the following proof:

> The Euclidean algorithm can be used to express $x := gcd(a, b)$ in the form $x = ma + nb$ with $m, n \in Z$.
>
> Use this fact to prove the following: if $p$ is a prime number and $p$
>   divides the product $kl$ (where $k, l ∈ Z$), then $p$ divides at least
>   one of $k $ and $l$.

I haven't got a clue at all where to start, but I have simple knowledge of Euclid's Lemma but just no idea how to use the expression given in order to prove this.

Comment: This can be extended to any euclidean domain :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say $p$ does not divide $k$.  Then gcd$(p,k)=1$.  It follows that we can find integers $a,b$ with $$ap+bk=1$$
Multiplying by $l$ yields $$apl+bkl=l$$
As $p$ divides both terms on the left it divides their sum.  Hence $p|l$.

Comment: I understand that p divides the first term on the left, but how does it divide the second?

Comment: Well, by assumption $p|(kl)$ hence $p|(bkl)$.

Comment: Ah, that's so obvious lol! thanks